# How to create a df that gets sum of columns based on a groupby column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
country   year    gender    measure               value0 ... value12
 A         2000    1         vaccinated_at_month   2      ... 1
 B         2000    1         vaccinated_at_month   13     ... 12
 A         2000    0         vaccinated_at_month   4      ... 3
 A         2000    9         vaccinated_at_month   5      ... 4
 B         2000    0         walked_at_month       3      ... 13
 C         2001    1         vaccinated_at_month   6      ... 5
 C         2001    0         vaccinated_at_month   3      ... 2
```

I want to be able to remove the gender column and collapse all values into sums based on the previous categorical columns.

I have tried

```
df_new = df.groupby(['country', 'year', 'gender', 'measure'])['value0', ... 'value12'].apply(lambda x : x.astype(float).sum())
```

However, df_new still preserves the gender column. I am trying to get this outcome:

```
country   year       measure               value0      ... value12
 A         2000       vaccinated_at_month   11 (=2+4+5) ... 8 (=1+3+4)
 B         2000       vaccinated_at_month   13          ... 12
 B         2000       walked_at_month       3           ... 13
 C         2001       vaccinated_at_month   9 (=6+3)    ... 7 (=5+2)
 C         2001       vaccinated_at_month   3           ... 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is more appropriate at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) since it is more of a programming question.

However, I think you almost got it working. Just remove gender from your groupby:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['country', 'year', 'measure'])['value0', ... 'value12'].apply(lambda x : x.astype(float).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['country', 'year', 'measure'])['value0', '...', 'value12'].sum()
print(df_new)
```